# Python/HTML How to scrape webpage content without cookie advisor?

Tags: javascript, python, html, cookies

I'm trying to scrape the content of a webpage with Python and i'm able to get every content i need, but in the returned HTML there's also the cookie advisor. I want to remove it but i don't know how to exclude it from the XPath query or the HTML content. Here you can find the advisor in the footer of the page. [Webpage here](http://almatourism.unibo.it/article/view/5290)

```
#!C:/Python27/python
from lxml import etree
import requests
import cgi

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
q =fs.getfirst ("URL")

page = requests.get(q)

if q.find("http://www.dlib.org") != -1:
    tree = etree.HTML(page.text)
    element = tree.xpath('./body/form/table[3]/tr/td/table[5]')
else:
    p = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, resolve_entities=False)
    tree = etree.fromstring(page.content, p)
    element = tree.xpath('.//*[@id="content"]')

content = etree.tostring(element[0])

print "Content-type: text\n\n"
print content.strip()
```

Comment: what's a cookie advisor?, what are you using to scrape, what are you using the parse?

Comment: it's similar to a window alert, in Italy is mandatory for every website to give this information to the users that they are using cookies, so you have to accept or deny this information object every "first" time you visit the website.

For the scraping i'm using lxml with etree and json for create objects.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far

Comment: maybe use `import cookiejar` and pass it to urllib2 constructor, then call the url that sets the I-saw-the-message cookie?

Comment: @Poggio why are you using the cgi module? this code you have doesnt run for me at all

Comment: @heinst - you can run his code like so: `python foo.py URL=http://almatourism.unibo.it/article/view/5290 `

Comment: cause this script is used by a JS script.

Comment: I'd just go with `request` and `bs4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the page you specified, the cookies advisor exists in a `div` with an `id=cookiesAlert`. You can use `lxml.xpath()` to search for that `div` and remove it, like so:

```
if q.find("http://www.dlib.org") != -1:
    tree = etree.HTML(page.text)
    element = tree.xpath('./body/form/table[3]/tr/td/table[5]')
else:
    p = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, resolve_entities=False)
    tree = etree.fromstring(page.content, p)
    element = tree.xpath('.//*[@id="content"]')
    cookies_alert = element[0].xpath('.//*[@id="cookiesAlert"]')
    for ca in cookies_alert:
        ca.getparent().remove(ca)
```

Comment: Damn! It was so easy, thank you so much. Your code works, i was searching for that specified div but i don't know why i wasn't able to find it.